# MailComposer doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I tried out to create an email with the mailComposer.
The only thing which doesn't work is the attachment. I even tried out the mailComposer in the development documentation.
When I create an email, I can see the symbols or the image at the end of the email.
But as soon as I save the draft or send the email away, the attachments are empty.

What could it be?

Thanks

Comment: You going to have to post some code so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, it does not seem difficult.

http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/home/2009/7/14/how-to-make-your-iphone-app-send-email-with-attachments.html